Determining the value of PATH_MAX on UNIX-like systems
Below is the approach taken in the function allocpath() in the book "Advanced Programming in Unix Environment", which I have modified to simply determine the maximum size of the path.
FILENAME_MAX from <stdio.h> has not been used because the documentation for GNU C Library states:

Unlike PATH_MAX, this macro is defined even if there is no actual limit imposed. In such a case, its value is typically a very large number. This is always the case on GNU/Hurd systems.
Usage Note: Don’t use FILENAME_MAX as the size of an array in which to store a file name! You can’t possibly make an array that big!

glibc also seems to be using the same approach here: realpath().
For UNIX-like systems, Vim does not meddle with sysconf()/pathconf() and simply does:
/* Use the system path length if it makes sense. */
#if defined(PATH_MAX) && PATH_MAX > 1000
    #define PATH_MAXL    PATH_MAX
#else
    #define PATH_MAXL    1024
#endif

and similar for Windows.
CPython has a similar check as Vim.
Code:
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200819
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   700

#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#ifdef PATH_MAX
    static long path_max = PATH_MAX;
#else
    static long path_max = 0;
#endif /* PATH_MAX */

static long posix_version = 0;
static long xsi_version = 0;

/* If PATH_MAX is indeterminate, no guarantee this is adequate. */
#define PATH_MAX_GUESS  1024

ssize_t get_path_max(void) 
{
    if (path_max == 0) {        /* First time through. */
        errno = 0;
        if ((path_max = pathconf("/", _PC_PATH_MAX)) == -1) {
            if (errno != 0) {
                return -1;
            }

            path_max = PATH_MAX_GUESS;  /* It's indeterminate */
        } else {
            path_max++;     /* Add one since it is relative to root. */
        }
    }

    if (posix_version == 0) {
        if ((posix_version = sysconf(_SC_VERSION)) == -1) {
            return path_max;
        }
    }

    if (xsi_version == 0) {
        if ((xsi_version = sysconf(_SC_XOPEN_VERSION)) == -1) {
            return path_max;
        }
    }

    /* Before POSIX.1-2001, we aren't guaranteed that PATH_MAX includes
     * the terminating null byte. Same goes for XPG3.  */
    ssize_t size = path_max;

    if ((posix_version < 200112L) && (xsi_version < 4)) {
        return path_max + 1;
    }

    return path_max;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%zu\n", get_path_max());
}

Review Request:
Is this reliable? Can it be made more robust?

Your code already seems good (it follows C good practices and it's well written, overall).
These are the enhancements I'd implement:
1) Add bounds checking for the path_max value
#define MIN_PATH_LENGTH 256
#define MAX_PATH_LENGTH 32767  

I set MAX_PATH_LENGTH to a value that works on many modern systems, if you have particular requirements you may change it.
2) Generic function overhaul
ssize_t get_path_max(void) 
{
    if (path_max == 0) {
        errno = 0;
        path_max = pathconf("/", _PC_PATH_MAX);
        
        if (path_max == -1) {
            if (errno != 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            path_max = PATH_MAX_GUESS;
        } else {
            path_max++; /* Add one for root */
        }
        
        /* Sanity check the value */
        if (path_max < MIN_PATH_LENGTH) {
            path_max = MIN_PATH_LENGTH;
        } else if (path_max > MAX_PATH_LENGTH) {
            path_max = MAX_PATH_LENGTH;
        }
    }

    /* Cache POSIX/XSI versions */
    if (posix_version == 0) {
        posix_version = sysconf(_SC_VERSION);
        if (posix_version == -1) {
            posix_version = 200809L; /* Assume recent POSIX */
        }
    }

    if (xsi_version == 0) {
        xsi_version = sysconf(_SC_XOPEN_VERSION);
        if (xsi_version == -1) {
            xsi_version = 700; /* Assume recent XSI */
        }
    }

    /* Add space for null terminator for older standards */
    if ((posix_version < 200112L) && (xsi_version < 4)) {
        return path_max + 1;
    }

    return path_max;
}

This approach is more reliable than using FILENAME_MAX and provides better portability across different UNIX-like systems. The bounds checking helps prevent possibly wrong values, while still maintaining flexibility for different systems.
